# Error Trapping Error

Tags: android, error-handling

Trying to catch a null or 0 input. If a null input is made, the app crashes, if a 0 is input, it passes through the error and returns strange math!

```
case_cost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.case_cost);
dilution = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dilution);
answer =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
ounces_pc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ounces_pc);

Button finishBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
finishBtn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Method 
        if (((Float.valueOf(dilution.getText().toString())) == 0) ||   
                         (dilution.getText().equals(null)))   {

    String errMsg = "Missing Dilution";
        answer.setText(errMsg);

    }   else;
```

Debug Info:

```
StringToReal.invalidReal(String, boolean) line: 63  
StringToReal.parseFloat(String) line: 289   
Float.parseFloat(String) line: 300  
Float.valueOf(String) line: 337 
UccActivity$1.onClick(View) line: 47    
Button(View).performClick() line: 4102  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 17063 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 615   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 155 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5454    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not   
available [native method]   
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1029 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 796 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the check for Null before the check for a value.  Otherwise, when it checks against the 0 and the value is Null, it will throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will allow you to input invalid strings (letters) and not crash (Yours will as is). Additionally, your 0 check isn't working since you are comparing an int to a float.. you should be using 0f

```
String text = dilution.getText().toString();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
  answer.setText("Empty input");
  return;
}

try {
    Float value = Float.valueOf(text);

    if (value == null || value == 0f) {
        answer.setText("Zero");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    answer.setText("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't believe you will ever get null from getText().toString() on an EditText.. It will just return an empty non-null String ( "" ) if the field is blank

Comment: Thanks for the help, not only the code, but helping understand "WHY".

Comment: If you think this is the best solution please mark it as the answer :)